# Node/Express + MySQL, Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR. The data is being inserted correctly but the error still shows up

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

First time using MySQL, I created a simple login/register app.

I'm very confused because in my noob eyes the error doesn't seem to point to a place I can find. Plus the data is being inserted into the table correctly, so the error doesn't seem to be in the MySQL query.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', `affectedRows` = 1, `insertId` = 15, `serverStatus` = 2, `warningCount` = 0, `' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    --------------------
    at Pool.query (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
    at Promise (internal/util.js:274:30)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Pool.query (internal/util.js:273:12)
    at User.find (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/core/user.js:18:14)
    at /Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/routes/pages.js:58:22
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/core/user.js:43:13)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Query._callback (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:491:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/pablosouza/Desktop/Projects/Tests/db2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Any thoughts?

```
//User class to send queries to database

const pool = require ('./pool');
const bcrypt = require ('bcrypt'); //to hash the password 

function User () {}; //creating on object

User.prototype = {
    // Find user data by id or username
    find: function(user = null, callback)
    {
        if(user) {
            var field = Number.isInteger(user) ? 'id' : 'username';
        }

        let sql = `SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE ${field} = ?`;

        pool.query(sql, user, function(err,result){
            if(err) throw err
            if(result.length) {
                callback(result[0]);
            }else {
                callback(null);
            }
        });
    },

    create : function(body, callback) {
        let pwd = body.password;
        body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(pwd,10);

        var bind = [];

        for (prop in body){
            bind.push(body[prop]);
        }

        let sql = "INSERT INTO users1 (username, fullname, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

        pool.query(sql, bind, function(err, lastId){
            if(err) 
            console.log("oops this is bullshit");
            callback(lastId);
        });
    },

    login: function(username, password, callback){
        this.find(username, function(user){
            if(user) {
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
                    callback(user);
                    return;
                }
            }
            callback(null);
        })
    }


}

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using prepared statements than you have to enclose the variables to be inserted inside an array like this

```
pool.query(sql, [user], function(err,result){
            if(err) throw err
            if(result.length) {
                callback(result[0]);
            }else {
                callback(null);
            }
        });
```

Do this and then tell